# Get access to a chunk of code

Tags: c#, regex

**My progress**

I converted my input file to bytes using the File function. And converted this byte to strings using .ToString method.
Now, I have a big pile of dynamically compiled strings. What I need to do is to get access to a chunk of it which contains an expression of the form 
`x=(exp1)?b:c` using C#.

**What I have already done?**
I have tried using pointers. But I recently learned that using pointers is getting redundant and is also considered unsafe.

**Where am I stuck?** 
I know I can use foreach loop to traverse the string and get access to individual char. But I am stuck at the next step.

**What I have in my mind?**
I read about Regular expressions. And I can use that to access that particular chunk of code which I require.

**My question?**
Is there a better way of solving my problem? Better and less complex.

**Why?** Because I want to apply my algorithm to only that part of the code where `x=(exp1)?b:c` lies

Comment: Do you have your file data? Showing relevant pieces of it would be of great help.

Comment: why not use `if-else` to check for presence of your expression??also give some inputs for testing

Comment: @rock321987 the problem is to move from a pile of string to that chunk where x=(exp1)?b:c lies.  Because I have apply my algorithm to only this part of the code.

Comment: you can use `index of` or something like that to find the index of that expression

Comment: Worked. Thanks @rock321987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regular expression**

You can capture the data after expression using the following regex (first capturing group will contain the data)

```
x=\(exp1\)\?b:c(.*)
```

**Better Solution**

Use `IndexOf` to find the position of your `expression` and use it

```
str.IndexOf(expression)
```